# subprocess Popen: signal not propagating

Tags: python, subprocess, signals

execute_sleep.py

```
import os
import time
import subprocess

sleep_script = 'sleep_forever.py'
child = subprocess.Popen(sleep_script,
                         shell=True,
                         close_fds=True,
                         stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                         stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
                        )

subout = child.communicate()[0]
print subout
rc = child.returncode
```

sleep_forever.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import time

while True:
    time.sleep(1)
```

When I run execute_sleep.py and then `kill -TERM -- -<pid of execute_sleep.py>`,
execute_sleep.py dies but sleep_forever.py keeps running.

What can I do so that when execute_sleep.py gets signal, it propagates down to sleep_forever.py?

Do any of these options block signals?

- `shell=True`
- `close_fds=True`
- the use of `subprocess.PIPE`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to handle the signal, otherwise you are creating orphans (sleep_script processes). So that when the signal to terminate the father process is caught it propagates to child processes before.

```
def handler(signum, frame):
    functionToKillSleeper(pidtokill)


signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, handler)
```

## Note that SIGKILL cannot be caught.

So you will need to SIGINT or SIGTERM the father process in order for the signal to be handled, otherwise your problem will remain.

Comment: i dont want signal to be handled (?). i just want it to be propagated. it looks like its not even receiving any signals to be handled. are you saying the parent process needs to explicitly prop gate the signal down? -_-

Comment: Yes, signal must be handled in order to propagate otherwise as I've written your creating orphan child processes. Because the processes are now independent.

Comment: ohh i thought if they are in the same process group (and they would be in the same group, the parent and the child process), the signal is propagated automatically. i suppose that assumption is wrong?

Comment: Yes, what the OS is doing is creating a fork of the original process and both go their own way, so even though one is child of the other, when the father dies, the child process continues independently of the father thus creating an orphan process, that you need to terminate on itself. 
So if you are creating new processes you will always need to create a clean exit, and should have functions to eliminate child processes, and clean memory (its python so don't worry about that) etc..